# Groovy: tap vs with

Tags: groovy

Groovy has `tap`and `with` functions. What is the difference between them

```
def user = new User('john', 1)
        .tap {userService.save(it)}

def user2 = new User('Alex', 2)
        .with {userService.save(it)}
```

`userService` updates the record and returns updated record.

```
class UserService {
    public User save(final User user) {
        // save user
        return updated // Id, lastmodified and other fields can be updated.
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have the answer to your question: [Groovy Goodness: Easy Object Creation With Tap Method](https://dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-easy-object-creation-with-tap-meth)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tap` always returns `it` no matter having a return statement or not but `with` will return the result of the last statement or statement that you explicitly return.

In your question, `user` will always the same object as created by new statement. However, `user2` will be the return value of `userService.save(it)`

Answer (score 8):

Chayne's answer really covers it and we should leave it as accepted, but I figured I would add an answer to "why do we in fact have two different methods".

With tap you can do things like:

```
def u = new User().tap {
  firstName = "Brother"
  lastName = "Bob"
}
```

without having to explicitly return `it` as you would have to with `with`:

```
def u = new User().with {
  firstName = "Brother"
  lastName = "Bob"
  it
}
```

`with` has been part of groovy for a long time, `tap` is a newer addition and it is explicitly there to support this kind of "return the modified object" pattern.

Now that we have `tap`, it leaves `with` as more appropriate in side effecting scenarios like this:

```
server.with {
    name = application.name
    status = status
    sessionCount = 3
    start()
    stop()
}
```

(example shamelessly stolen from the groovy docs)

where we are uninterested in the return value and just want to perform some operations on an object.

To further confuse things, it turns out that groovy has added a variant of `with` with a boolean argument `with(boolean returnIt)` where `xxx.with(true) {}` will get you the behavior of `tap` above and `xxx.with(false) {}` will give you the behavior of `with` without the argument.

Answer (score 2):

If `userService.save(it)` returns a `boolean` then `user` will be a `User` and `user2` will be a `boolean`